# Android arrayList whole items is replaced by last one

Tags: android, arraylist, cursor, duplicates

I use the following code to fetch rows from a table. When I first iterate through the group the first item is added to the array list and it shows the exact values. After the second iteration the first object got replaced by the second object and now there is two duplicate elements. What could be the reason behind that?

```
c.moveToFirst();
        ArrayList<BaseModel> userShares = new ArrayList<BaseModel>();
        for (int count=0;count<recordCount;count++) {
            UserShareModel userShareModel = (UserShareModel) model;
            userShareModel.setUserId(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("userid")));
            userShareModel.setType(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("type")));
            userShareModel.setKeyUserShare(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("key_user_share")));
            userShareModel.setSecretSeed(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("secret_seed")));
            userShareModel.setValueUserShare(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("value_user_share")));
            userShareModel.setCreatedAt(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("created_at")));
            String updatedAt = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("updated_at"));
            if (updatedAt != null) {
                userShareModel.setUpdatedAt(updatedAt);
            }
            userShares.add(userShareModel);
            c.moveToNext();
        }
```

Comment: Where is `model` coming from?

Comment: Inside this function the above code is written                                                   public ArrayList<BaseModel> get(BaseModel model)

Comment: I have added an answer but you design is probably not correct. I don't see your argument `model` used anywhere in the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the same `BaseModel model` instance to populate data in each iteration. So all your array list references point to the same object (same object with data that was updated at the end).

You should create a new instance of `BaseModel model` in each loop iteration.

```
for (int count=0;count<recordCount;count++) {
UserShareModel userShareModel = new UserShareModel ();
//setters
userShares.add(userShareModel);
c.moveToNext();
}
```

Comment: If you are downvoting have the courtesy to provide reason? Further course of action can then be taken. Just downvoting helps no one!

Answer (score 0):

I do it normaly like this:

```
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            UserShareModel userShareModel = (userShareModel.setUserId(c.getString(0)), .... usw //probably working with getColumnIndexOrThrow("userid")));


            userShares.add(userShareModel);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
```